# How to connect a Django view with angular js Front end?

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm fairly new to Django rest and angularjs. I'm trying to create a Django view which will have a function and this function has to be called via a button in angular js. Can anyone please help me out? 
Thanks

Comment: Check out [django-angular](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say this is your Django/python api end point (assume controller file to be random.py)

```
def getRandomInfo(request):
try:
    result = database.getRandomInfo()
    return JsonResponse(result, content_type="application/json", safe=False)
except Exception as e:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc(e)
    return JsonResponse({error:'sorry'}, content_type="application/json", safe=False)
```

Via angular, provided you have resolved all the dependencies and have a functioning angular app and/or controller set up in your html/js

you can call the api using below code

```
app.controller("appControllerName", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("{% url 'getRandomInfo' %}")
            .success(function (response, status) {
                response_data = response
                $scope.data = response_data;
            }).error(function (response, status) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });
  }
```

if you notice the {% url 'getRandomInfo' %} , this is defined in your urls.py , u'll have to add a line like this over there where getRandomInfo will have to be the 'name' of the url

```
url(r'^random/getRandomInfo/$',random.getRandomInfo, name='getRandomInfo'),
```

Over here you controller name is random and a function within that controller is def getRandomInfo, so django allows two ways to access this endpoint, either via the url r'^random/getRandomInfo/$ (yes regex is allowed here) or via the name as stated in the example here.

Best of Luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot will try it out

Answer (score 2):

This might help:
[Django - Angular Tutorial](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial#learning-django-and-angularjs)

General answer would be:
1) Using for example Django REST expose your method (endpoint)
2) From Angular application send request to the previously exposed endpoint.

Comment: Thanks will try it out

Comment: +1 for referring thinkster, i started my journey from there but you have to use some code for the answer that would be a great reference for everybody

Comment: @Shift N' Tab - Yes, you are probably right, but the question was too general, so I thought that it would be the best option for original poster to start with some good tutorial

Comment: @nick79 Thanks the tutorials are very helpful

Comment: @user7585518 glad to see that you are satisfied.